# Lebesgue covering dimension for locales

Tags: locales

A space $(X,\tau)$ is said to have *Lebesgue covering dimension $\leq n$* (for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$) if every open covering $\cal U$ has a refinement $\cal V$ such that for every $x\in X$ the set ${\cal V}_x := \{V\in \mathcal{V}: x\in V\}$ has at less than $n$ elements. (Note that $n$ is "globally fixed" for all open coverings $\cal U$.) If there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(X,\tau)$ has Lebesgue dimension $\leq n$ then $(X,\tau)$ is said to have infinite Lebesgue dimension.

Now, points are crucially involved in this definition (I am referring to the sets $\mathcal{V}_x$).

Can the definition of the Lebesgue covering dimension for topological spaces be extended to locales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that a space $X$ has Lebesgue covering dimension less than or equal to $n$ if and only if whenever $\mathcal{U}$ is an open covering, there is some refinement $\mathcal{V}$ so that whenever $O_{0},...,O_{n+1}\in\mathcal{V}$ are distinct we have $O_{0}\cap...\cap O_{n+1}=\emptyset$. This notion can be extended to locales in the obvious way. In particular, we say that a frame $L$ has Lebesgue covering dimension at most $n$ if whenever $C\subseteq L$ and $\bigvee C=1$, there is some $D\subseteq L$ with $\bigvee D=1$, for all $d\in D$ there is some $c\in C$ with $d\leq c$, and where if $x_{0},...,x_{n+1}\in D$ are distinct, then $x_{0}\wedge...\wedge x_{n+1}=0$. I am not aware if the point-free version of the Lebesgue covering dimension has been studied already, but point-free topology has not been well developed, so it seems like someone would study the point-free Lebesgue covering dimension in the future.

Comment: You presumably meant to say also that $D$ should be a refinement of $C$.

Comment: Isbell in [Graduation and dimension in locales](https://books.google.ge/books?id=Ms9uRvYl4pAC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=graduation+and+dimension+in+locales&source=bl&ots=2rk16ETYxs&sig=_jXIEcvUT8o_PsG8KrKy7FhesUk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=graduation%20and%20dimension%20in%20locales&f=false) analyses this. He comes up with several variations on cover refinement, resulting in some very interesting dimension functions. For example, "$D$ refines $C$" is replaced by "generates larger lattice", and "more than $n$ intersect trivially" is replaced by "generated lattice has height $\leqslant n$".